# Traveling to Belarus with dual citizenship

Tags: customs-and-immigration, paperwork, dual-nationality, belarus, belarusian-citizens

I will be travelling to Belarus soon and I have this little riddle to solve.

I have 2 cizitenship - Czech and Belarus. As far as I know, I always need to show my belarusian passport to belarusian authorities. So... leaving EU zone through Poland, I show my czech passport at polish customs, belarusian one in Belarus. When going back - vice versa.

Is my idea correct? Or belarusian custom officers may have curious questions about "how will I enter EU zone without visa"?

Main reason why I am asking this is, that dual cizizenship is legal in Czech, but not in Belarus.

Thank you for all ideas!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dual citizenship *is* allowed, but as you said, you must use your Belarusian passport to enter and exit Belarus.

If asked on exit how you'll enter the EU, say you have a Czech passport.